# How to swap cursor and call getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader() when the class extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, simplecursoradapter

I am facing a challenge where i have to extend a class with SimpleCursorAdapter and at the same time implement it with LoaderCallbacks.Generally in an activity we use adapter.swapCursor(cursor) in onLoaderFinished().But since this class itself extend to SimpleCursorAdapter, i don't have any instance to tie it with.

```
public class SpinnerEntitiesAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

 public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

   }
}
```

i am trying to call getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader() in the adapter constructor but don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your class is extending Cursor adapter and also implemented Loaders then onLoadFinished you can directly write swapCursor(cursor)

Comment: @SilvansSolanki dude!!! the cursor only returning one item... onLoadFinish has 7 item but spinner only populate 1 item...

Comment: put your adapter code here